# Undefined index btn php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una página con una vista principal, que tiene el botón de buscar usuario, cargar usuario y mostrar lista de usuarios.

Todos finalmente acaban llamando a la controladora que tiene funciones de acuerdo al `value` de los botones. Me funcionan perfecto, salvo el de lista de usuarios, que me dice:

> undefined index btn

en todas las lineas donde esta `btn` en la controladora principal (no sólo en el de lista de usuarios), cuando en el resto de los btn no me dice eso!

**Principal**

```html
<h1>Sistema de Gestion de Multas</h1>
    <a href="altapersonas.html"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btn" value="cargar">Cargar usuario</button></a> //Esto me lleva a la pagina de alta personas, la cual llama a la controladora desde el action del formulario 
<form method="post" action="../controladoras/controladoraprincipal.php">
//formulario
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="btn" value="agregar">Agregar</button>
```

Cuando llega a la controladora, sabe qué hacer mediante

```php
if ($_POST["btn"] == "agregar")
{
    if (empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['apellido'])  || empty($_POST['dni']) || empty($_POST['direccion']) || empty($_POST['fechanacimiento']))
        throw new Exception('Debe pasar todos los valores');
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $fechanacimiento = $_POST['fechanacimiento'];
    $persona1 = new Persona ($nombre, $apellido, $dni, $direccion, $fechanacimiento);
    $daop->agregar($persona1);
    $listado = $daop->todas();

    require_once ('../vistas/listadeusuarios.php');
}
```

Y así funciona perfecto. Ahora, cuando mando directo de la vista principal a la controladora con el botón "Lista de usuarios":

```html
<a href="../controladoras/controladoraprincipal.php">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btn" value="lista">Listado de usuarios
</button></a>
```

**controladora principal**

```php
$daop= new PersonaJsonDao();

if ($_POST["btn"] == "lista")
{
    $listado = $daop->todas();
    require_once('../vistas/listadeusuarios.php');
}
```

**El resultado es**

> Notice: Undefined index: btn in
>   C:\wamp\www\proyectomultas\controladoras\controladoraprincipal.php on
>   line 13 Call Stack
>   Time  Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0019  149288  {main}( )   ..\controladoraprincipal.php:0

Y me marca que ese error está en todas las líneas donde esta `btn`. Ssin embargo en el resto de las líneas donde esta `btn`, cuando lo uso no me marca ese error.

Comment: ¿Porque creas el formulario después de crear el botón de Cargar usuario?¿Puedes mostrar el html referente al formulario completo?

Comment: .. y porque usas un `<button>` dentro de un `<a>`?

Comment: Hola error404, no cree el formulario ahi, me exprese mal, quise poner que eso me lleva al html del formulario de carga! ahi en esa vista solo esta el boton que me lleva hasta el!

Comment: Y aldanux, yo habia hecho solamente el button, pero no sabia como hacer para que ese button me llevara hasta la pagina de la controladora, asi que se me ocurrio ponerle un <a> con la direccion de la controladora! 

Solo me enseñaron llamar a la controladora mediante los form, luego nunca me enseñaron a darle funcionalidad a los botones para que me lleven hacia algun lado asi que busque y encontre esa solucion! Si hay alguna mejor bienvenida sera! Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes enviar, tal cual como lo tienes, mediante un `<a>` y por `POST` el valor del `<button>`.

El `<button>` debería ir en un `<form>`:

```
<form method="post" action="../controladoras/controladoraprincipal.php"> 

   <!-- formulario -->

    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btn" value="lista">Listado de usuarios</button>
</form>
```

y en `controladoraprincipal.php`:

```
if (isset('btn') && $_POST['btn'] == 'lista') {

     // resto de código
}
```

Comment: Idola gracias!! me soluciono todo!°